# C# How to replace the variables inside strings

Tags: c#, string.format

```
string name = "name1";
string country = "country1";
string greet = "Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";
```

I got string from database
string with some variables.
I know `string.format()` or `$""` to replace,
but that can't solve.

The result I want to get is like

```
string result = $"Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";
```

How can I get this?

Comment: [string.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Comment: Why don't you `string result = greet.Replace("{name}", name);`?

Comment: the string I get from database, and I don't know how many variables that will be

Comment: Are you getting the `greet` from the database too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to `Replace` all `{...}` with a help of *Regular Expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  // All possible substitutions (from database?)
  Dictionary<string, string> replacements = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "name", "name1"},
      { "country", "country1"},
  };

  string greet = "Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
      greet,
    @"(?<=\{).*?(?=\})",
      match => replacements.TryGetValue(match.Value, out var value) ? value : "???");
```

**Edit:** If you want to remove `{`..`}` you can modify regular expression a bit:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
   greet,
 @"\{(?<name>.*?)\}",
   match => replacements.TryGetValue(match.Groups["name"].Value, out var value) ? value : "???");
```

Comment: Appears not to work as intended, this will leave {} around the replacement.

Comment: @O'Leg: I kept `{...}` *intentionally*: "The result I want to get is like `string result = $"Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";`", please note '{' and '}'. However, I've provided an edit - slightly changed regex - in case someone wants to get rid of `{` and `}`

Comment: this looks hardcoded? Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't see any hardcoding (except to demonstrate how to write such things), you can extract a method if you like; please fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YnsOTG

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
string name = "name1";
string country = "country1";
string result = String.Format("Hi {0}, Are you from {1}",name, country);
```

Or if you want to use `String.Replace`:

```
string name = "name1";
string country = "country1";
string result = greet.Replace("{name}",name).Replace("{country}",country);
```

And if you want to use `$`:

```
var name = "name1";
var country = "country1";
var result = $"Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";
```

Comment: I quote the question "I know `string.format()` ... but that can't solve"

Comment: @bradbury9 He claims he knows string.format() but do you see any correct implementation in his question?

Comment: variables inside strings don't have order, I can't find the index

Comment: @ThelemePan You need to have a logic for replacing string; Otherwise based on what are you going to replace the strings?

Comment: I think OP is getting the format string from the database though, so you can't use `string.Format`

Comment: @Karamafrooz The result i want to get is like `$greet`

Answer (score 3):

If you want only have many variables to replace, you can iterate by list:

```
string greet = "Hi {name}, Are you from {country}";
var placeholders = new List<(string placeholder, string value)>()
{
    ("name", "name1"),
    ("country1", "country1")
};

foreach (var ph in placeholders)
    greet = greet.Replace($"{{{ph.placeholder}}}", ph.value);
```

Comment: Better to use a `Dictionary` than a `List` of tuples.

Comment: `Dictonary` is more complex to add items than list. If you not have to search key `List`have better performance.

Comment: Typo in code; should be `greet = greet.Replace(...)`

Comment: Thanks your code @LeszekMazur !
I try add `StringComparison` to ignoring case inside { }